# GUI for name/dns server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind, nameservers

I'm currently running Plesk, which is rather expensive, just for name server and dns server.
I've read a lot abount BIND and tried to play with it. I've also tried out ProBIND as a GUI for BIND, but again, this failed.

Are there any GUI for BIND or similar for newbies like me, who just want to have a simple, small name server running with the ability to add/remove/edit domains and their DNS setup?

Any good tutorial will do.

i'm running Ubuntu (but could change Linux OS).

Comment: Here: http://tinyurl.com/brpjygd

Comment: belongs to superuser/serverfault

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to run your own DNS server?  Is there a reason you can't hand this off to an outside organization such as [DNSimple](http://dnsimple.com)?

Answer (score 1):

There's GADMIN-BIND packaged for ubuntu. Never used it though.